# Converting Editable (from an EditText) to Byte Array

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the value of an EditText box and convert it to a byte array for use in nfc writing.  Basically, I want to be able to write to an NFC tag just from an EditText box.  I've tried simple stuff like .toString() and UTF-8 encoding, but my issue seems to be in getting a String value from the Editable.  Anyone have experience here?

Edit:  Relevant code here:

```
EditText msgInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ...

String msg = msgInput.getText().toString();
Log.i(TAG, "msg: " + msg);

byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes();
Log.i(TAG, "bytes: " + bytes);

messagePayload = bytes;
```

I enter 'stuff' (without quotes) into my edittext, then try to write.  This gives two logcat outputs:

```
    msg: stuff
    bytes: [B@412e9e80
```

Comment: `toString()` should return a string representation of your `Editable` just fine. Could you be more specific about your issue?

Comment: Sorry-- so as to why toString() won't work, toString() returns something like '[B' plus some other junk, as part of the algorithm.  Works fine when displaying as a String, not so fine when converting to other formats.

Comment: try converting to a char array first using string.toCharArray()

Comment: Everybody and their brother uses `getText().toString()` to convert the contents of an `EditText` to a `String` (e.g., for saving in a database). I feel quite confident that it works and has done so for over four years. Perhaps post the code that is giving you grief, so we can see what it is that is not working for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably,

```
editBox.getText().toString().getBytes()
```

Comment: @atoombs Log.i(TAG, "bytes: " + bytes) is wrong, use Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(bytes))

Comment: That displays the bytes-- thanks for the help.  I guess I just don't know why the bytes of the message is throwing a FormatException when trying to create a new NdefMessage with that byte array.

Comment: @atoombs That FormatException issue can be asked here as a separate question, I think